# Why does polygon area change when projection is changed in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, area

I have a simple polygon in a given coordinate system (example see below) as a feature in a FGDB. I would like to re-project the polygon to ETRS 1989 LAEA (EPSG 3035) using the project tool (data management tools - projection and transformations).

So far this works fine, but looking at the output I stumble over two things I cannot explain.

1. The area of the polygon changes (e.g. from  16'000'000 m2 to 15'999'517 m2).
2. When adding the "old" polygon with the initial projection (on the fly projection) and the reprojected "new" polygon (epsg 3035) into the same data frame (set for epsg 3035) the two polygons are slightly set apart (see image)

My interpretation of these two observations is that the size as well as the location of the polygon was altered during the projection to EPSG 3035.

Does anybody know why this happens and how to avoid that?

Example for initial coordinate system:

```
Germany_Zone_4
WKID: 31494 Authority: Esri

Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 4500000,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 12,0
Scale_Factor: 1,0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397,155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078,962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299,1528128
```

[image: image showing polygon with initial projection (projected on the fly) and reprojected polygon (EPSG 3035)]

Comment: Projection, by definition, is basically a distortion of the polygon. So small differences in the areas should not be concerning.

Comment: For the different location it could be caused by different transformation between the reproject tool and the "on the fly" reprojection, check that you use the same transformation in both. (also the project tool has a "preserve shape" box that densify polygon before reprojecting using it may reduce the area difference)

Comment: Since you are surprised by the change in area you might want to read up on different coordinate systems, how they are created, what they distort and how one can be transformed into another.  A Google search will come up with many sites, here's one I hadn't seen before: https://www.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=31484c80dba54a058369dfb8e9ced549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have two questions and answers here.

The input coordinate system uses a conformal map projection, transverse Mercator / Gauss-Krüger. Conformal projections maintain local shapes and angles, not areas. It's using DHDN as the earth model. That's an older system that is definitely offset compared to a more recent geographic coordinate reference system like ETRS89 or WGS84.

The output coordinate reference system uses Lambert azimuthal equal area, which maintains areas but not angles or shapes. It's based on ETRS89 so there's an offset which is visible if you reproject on-the-fly (in ArcMap) without setting the same geographic/datum transformation used in the Project Tool.

You can set the transformation in ArcMap by opening the data frame properties (right-click the map and select properties). Select the Coordinate System tab and click the Transformations button. Whatever coordinate reference system is being used by the map, select the other one in the top box. In the bottom pull-down, select the top entry and OK all dialogs.

The majority of the offset is due to the different GeoCRS and not having a transformation  set. Some differences between the two features may be due to the geometry of the input feature. If the feature is built with two-point lines and is large, those line may need to have a little curve in the output coordinate reference system. You might try densifying the polygon before reprojecting it. There will also be differences due to changing from a conformal to an equal area projection and because the GeoCRS are different--different size and shape of the earth.